# I setup new Gatsby project. It got installed successfully but Why it is failing when I am starting the dev server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, tailwind-css, server-side-rendering

I create a new gatsby project. Using `gatsby init` command.

These are the options that I selected.
[image]

As you can see, It got installed successfully.

[image]

But when I am trying to run the project by using comman `npm run develop` or `npm start`.
It is getting failed.

You can see the errrors below.

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Loading PostCSS "tailwindcss" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
Require stack:
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/utils.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/ModuleFilenameHelpers.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/dist/utils/setupHooks.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/dist/index.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/dist/cjs.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/utils/start-server.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/services/start-webpack-server.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/services/index.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/state-machines/develop/services.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/state-machines/develop/index.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/commands/develop-process.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/.cache/tmp-59019-3pUT5r2fgh5f

(@/Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/.cache/blank.css)

File: .cache/blank.css

failed Building development bundle - 10.132s
ERROR in ./.cache/blank.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleError: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Loading PostCSS "tailwindcss" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
Require stack:
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/utils.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/ModuleFilenameHelpers.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/dist/utils/setupHooks.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/dist/index.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/dist/cjs.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/utils/start-server.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/services/start-webpack-server.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/services/index.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/state-machines/develop/services.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/state-machines/develop/index.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/commands/develop-process.js
- /Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/.cache/tmp-59019-3pUT5r2fgh5f

(@/Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/.cache/blank.css)
    at Object.emitError (/Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:608:6)
    at getPostcssOptions (/Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/utils.js:222:19)
    at Object.loader (/Users/prabalsaxena/personal/projects/website/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:57:42)
 @ ./.cache/app.js 25:0-21

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
develop compiled with 2 errors
```

I have tried -

1. cleaning up the cache.
2. Installing the packages again.
3. Trying with different versions.

Current node version: v14.19.1
The machine I am using: Mac with M1 Chip.

Answer (score 0):

It lacks of scope or more detailed trials, but I'd try a combination of:

- Adding the following to your `package.json`:

  ```
  "workspaces": {
        "nohoist": [
            "@tailwindcss/forms",
            "@tailwindcss/forms/**"
        ]
    },
  ```
- Delete all `node_modules` and reinstalling them again.
- Run:

  ```
  npm install -W tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
  ```
- Install the package with -D flag:

  ```
  npm i -D tailwindcs
  ```
- Add the dependencies as devDependencies:

  ```
  {
     "devDependencies": {
       "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
       "postcss": "^8.4.12",
       "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
     },
  }
  ```